# Сравнение символов функцией strcmp()

Tags: массивы, c++

Есть некая функция:

```
void slovo(char *stroka)
{
...
if( strcmp(stroka[i]," ")!=0)
...
}
```

При компиляции компилятор выдаёт такую ошибку:

> error C2664: 'strcmp' : cannot convert
> parameter 1 from 'char' to 'const char
> *'

Не понимаю, что не так... Мне нужно сравнить символ из массива с пробелом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делайте проверку так (если вы хотите найти пробел в строке):

> if (stroka[i] == ' '){}

в этом случае у вас сравниваются два одинаковых типа данных (char)

Answer (score 10):

```
if (stroka[i] != ' ') {
   // Это сравнение i-го символа из строки с пробелом
   // здесь он не равен пробелу.
}
```

Внимательно прочитайте man 3 strcmp

```
if (strcmp(stroka," ") != 0) {
   // Это сравнение всей строки с строкой из одного пробела
}

if (strcmp(&stroka[i]," ") != 0) {
   // А это сравнение конца строки (начиная с i-го символа) 
   // с строкой из одного пробела
   // тот же результат даст вызов strcmp(stroka+i," ")
```

Почитайте про адресную арифметику и представление в памяти массивов и строк.

Answer (score 1):

вообще лучше использовать стандартную библиотеку STL и тип string. У него есть метод compare
посмотрите ссылку ниже
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Answer (score 1):

strcmp() сравнивает строки (фанатам STL просьба не исправлять на "массивы символов"), а не символы. Если вам нужно сравнить символы, никакие функции не нужны, пишите в условии char1 == char2, и всё.

Answer (score 0):

```
void slovo(char *stroka)
{
    ...
    if (strcmp(stroka[i], " ") != 0)
        ...
}
```

Как уже писали, `strcmp()` сравнивает строки. В вашем случае индексация массива `stroka[i]` передаёт функции символ (`char`), а функция ожидает строку (`const char *`).

Answer (score 0):

> сделай пробел типом char и тогда сравнивай их

```
char space[1]=" "
if (stroka[i] == space[0] )
```

Comment: Непонятно зачем массив размера 1, если можно сделать `char space = ' ';`, или вообще сравнивать напрямую с `' '`.